# Get table rows by multiple/end column value status

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I have a table with example data like below:

```
InquiryId   status
-------------------
 inquiry1    New
 inquiry1    Started
 inquiry1    Done
 inquiry2    New
 inquiry2    Pending
 inquiry3    New
 inquiry3    Started
 inquiry4    New
 inquiry4    Cancelled
```

..and so on

Each inquiry starts with status as New and can reach either of the end status'es (Done, Cancelled..) via the middle status'es (Started, Pending..)

The question is how do find the list of inquiries that started with New but never reached the end status, i.e. what SQL query needs to be written to get the list of uncompleted inquiries.

P.S: Using Sybase Database

Answer (score 1):

You can user the following query:

```
select distinct InquiryId
from <table_name>
where status not in('Done','Cancelled');
```

It will return all all the `InquiryId` which doesn't have the status as `Done` or `Cancelled` and is still in intermediate state.

Comment: But this query will also give me inquiryIds which are in New, Pending, Started status which I don't want. The requirement is to get all inquiries which started with New but never reached the end status

Comment: For this you can use nested query and work upon the output produced by this query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where status = 'New' and 
      not exists (select 1 
                  from table t1 
                  where t1.InquiryId = t.InquiryId and 
                        t1.status in ('Done', 'Cancelled')
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use aggregation:

```
select inquiryId
from t
group by inquiryId
having sum(case when status = 'New' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when status in ('Done', 'Cancelled') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The conditions in the `having` clause count the number of rows for each `inquiryId` that meet the given conditions.  The `> 0` says that the `inquiryId` has at least one row.  The `= 0` says that the `inquiryId` has more than one row.